# Magento 2 - How to get state code in footer email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, footer

Using `{{config path="general/store_information/region_id"}}` in `[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Email/email/footer.html`, I am getting region id. I would want region code to be displayed in footer of all the outgoing emails.

**UPDATE**
This code is added to footer.html to print the store information.

```
<p class="address">
            <span class="street-line1"> {{config path="general/store_information/street_line1"}} </span>
            <span class="street-line2"> {{config path="general/store_information/street_line2"}}, </span>
            <span class="city"> {{config path="general/store_information/city"}}, </span>
            <span class="region"> {{config path="general/store_information/region_id"}} </span>
            <span class="postcode"> {{config path="general/store_information/postcode"}} </span>
            <span class="phone">
            | <span class="number"> {{config path="general/store_information/phone"}} </span>
            </span>  
        </p>
```

This prints 97 for MA(Massachusetts). I want **MA** to be printed instead of 97

[image]

Comment: Please add the code for email template

Comment: <span>{{config path="general/store_information/region_id"}}</span>

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal code added.

Comment: Can you please confirm if region_id is set ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal yes it is set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get Region/State code in the footer using `{{config path="general/store_information/region_id"}}` and call it in your custom footer by loading new footer. The Footer code will look like the below:

```
<!-- End Content -->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="footer">
                    <p class="closing">{{trans "Thank you, %store_name" store_name=$store.frontend_name}}!</p>
                    <p class="region_code">{{config path="general/store_information/region_id"}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Add/Update your region ID from admin:

```
Stores -> General -> Store Information -> Region/State
```

[image]

**Hope it helps you!**

Comment: Once you select the country, the region field is loaded with states within that country. When I set the region to Massachusetts, it prints 97 as region_id. I want it to print MA.

Answer (score 0):

I had to override address renderer to achieve this.
So I wrote an around plugin like this

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <!-- add region code in store address-->
    <type name="Magento\Store\Model\Address\Renderer">
        <plugin name="addRegionCode" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\Model\Address\Renderer" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Plugin/Model/Address/Renderer.php

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\Model\Address;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager;
use Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory;


/**
 * Class Renderer used for formatting a store address
 */
class Renderer
{
    // here I changed region to region_code and added span classes as 
    // I wanted to apply some css
    const DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = "<span class='name'>{{var name}}</span>\n" .
        "<span class='street1'>{{var street_line1}},</span>\n" .
        "{{depend street_line2}}<span class='street2'>{{var street_line2}},</span>\n{{/depend}}" .
        "{{depend city}}<span class='city'>{{var city}}</span>,{{/depend}} <span class='region'>{{var region_code}}</span> {{depend postcode}}<span class='post'>{{var postcode}}</span>{{/depend}}\n" .
        "<span class='country'>, {{var country}}</span>";
    /**
     * @var EventManager
     */
    protected $eventManager;

    /**
     * @var FilterManager
     */
    protected $filterManager;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $template;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param RegionFactory $regionFactory
     * @param RegionFactory $eventManager
     * @param RegionFactory $filterManager
     * @param string $template
     */
    public function __construct(
        RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        FilterManager $filterManager,
        $template = self::DEFAULT_TEMPLATE
    ) {
        $this->regionFactory = $regionFactory;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->filterManager = $filterManager;
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\Address\Renderer $result
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @return \Magento\Store\Model\Address\Renderer
     */
    public function aroundFormat(\Magento\Store\Model\Address\Renderer $result, callable $proceed, $storeInfo, $type = 'html')
    {
        
        $this->eventManager->dispatch('store_address_format', ['type' => $type, 'store_info' => $storeInfo]);
        $regionCode = $this->getRegionData($storeInfo->getRegionId());
        //here I am setting region_code in data.
        $storeInfo->setData('region_code', $regionCode);
        $address = $this->filterManager->template(
            $this->template,
            ['variables' => $storeInfo->getData()]
        );
        if ($type == 'html') {
            $address = nl2br($address);
        }
        return $address;
    }
    
    /**
     * get region code
     * @param int $regionId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRegionData( $regionId ){
    $region = $this->regionFactory->create()->load($regionId);
    return $region->getData('code');
    }
}
```

and changed code in

app/design/frontend/MyVendor/MyTheme/Magento_Email/email/footer.html

```
<p class="address">
            {{var store.getFormattedAddress()|raw}}
            <span class="phone">
            | <span class="number"> {{config path="general/store_information/phone"}} </span>
            </span>  
        </p>
```

getFormattedAddress at the end calls format method of Renderer.php. SO modified Renderer.php above.